# Apache VirtualHost - many subdomains with same serveradmin

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

If I have multiple subdomains in an Apache vhost file, and they all have the same ServerAdmin, can I put the ServerAdmin directive once at the top outside of the VirtualHost tags? I also have multiple domains each with their own file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

So instead of this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin     EMAIL
   DocumentRoot    /PATH/TO/WEB/FILES
   ServerName      SERVERNAME1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin     EMAIL
   DocumentRoot    /PATH/TO/WEB/FILES
   ServerName      SERVERNAME2
</VirtualHost>
```

can I do this?

```
ServerAdmin     EMAIL

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot    /PATH/TO/WEB/FILES
   ServerName      SERVERNAME1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot    /PATH/TO/WEB/FILES
   ServerName      SERVERNAME2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Will there be another server-wide ServerAdmin setting, or just one?

Comment: I also have multiple domains each with their own file in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Are you asking if I plan to repeat this pattern in those other files?

Answer (score 0):

The `ServerAdmin` directive can be set in the server context, but only one (the last one to load, I think?) will be inheriting down to vhosts - so this will work if you do it once, and fail if you do it twice.

Maybe look into other options, like a shared `Include` file in each vhost definition?

Comment: So the 2nd code block I have in my question will work?